# Redirecting to bookmarked page after authentication in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

When the user clicks on some secured page or try to open some bookmarked page(which is a secured page), if the user is not authenticated then user will be redirected to login , and then after authentication , user must be redirected to the requested secured page.

Please help me to achieve this using sails.js. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried in config/bootstrap.js , but no idea on how to achieve this

Comment: I tried one method ie in policies/authenticated.js , i stored req.url(ie requested url) in session and redirected to login , once user authenticated , the user is redirected back to the req.url. This works.

Comment: Great!  Glad you were able to solve it.  Feel free to post your solution as answer and accept it so that others can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried one method ie in policies/authenticated.js , i stored req.url(ie requested url) in session and redirected to login , once user authenticated , the user is redirected back to the req.url. This works.